# What is the complexity of minimising a convex quadratic function over the integers?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

The problem of interest is
$$
\min_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \frac{1}{2}x^\top Q x + c^\top x
$$
where $Q$ is a positive definite matrix. I am reasonably sure this can't be solved in poly-time, since the closest lattice vector problem (in $\ell_2$ norm) can be reformulated in the above form. Do we have a proof of $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness for a corresponding decision problem - does there exist $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ so that the above quadratic takes a value less than or equal to $f^* \in \mathbb{R}$?

I don't find a proof of $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness of the closest lattice vector problem in $\ell_2$ norm. If such a proof is found, then this problem is solved.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Hardness_results, https://mathoverflow.net/q/9531/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33828/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160053/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest lattice vector problem is NP-hard in the $L_2$ norm.  See [NP completeness of closest vector problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33828/755) for a reference to the proof.

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be some inconsistencies among the links/answers. For example, the answer in the link you posted says "the shortest vector problem is $NP$-hard for any $L_p$ norm other that $L_\infty$". The cited paper by Micciancio also seems to suggest that it is hard under reverse unfaithful random reductions (and possibly not in general). Does that affect the original question?

Comment: @Sriram, that's not what it says.  It says "it is not known that...".  Saying "It is not known that X" is different from saying "X".  It is known that SVP is NP-hard for $L_\infty$.  For $L_p$ with $p \ne \infty$, it is not known whether SVP is NP-hard (but there is evidence that it is hard).  No, this doesn't affect my answer or the original question, as you are not asking about SVP -- you are asking about CVP.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!